# Voltage/Frequency characteristics as a motor dies off

Tags: motor, generator

So, hopefully this is a simple enough answer for someone.  I was recently posed a question concerning the coastdown characteristics of a pump as they pertain to the trip setpoints of a breaker.  One electrical bus supplies two water pumps, similar in design.  They're both 6900V, 3-phase motors.   The load breakers do not interlock directly with the feed breaker, rather, they are designed to trip on either low voltage (5300V, 0.8s delay, or immediately upon reaching 4900V) or low frequency (57Hz, 0.4s delay).

The question posed was whether the load breaker would first trip on voltage or frequency, in the event of a feed breaker trip.  My thought is that once the supply voltage is gone, the pump will, in effect, act as a generator and power the bus during coastdown.  This is mostly irrelevant, obviously both pumps are coasting down, but it will influence which trip setpoint is reached first.  I understand the frequency characteristic will be proportional to the speed of the pump as it coasts down, but I'm not sure of the voltage response.

I realize this isn't nearly enough information to do calculations on, but I'm not looking for a full engineering analysis, just a prod in the right direction.  Thanks for any insights!

Edit:  In response to Brian Drummond:  Yes, it is a squirrel-cage induction motor.

Edit:  In response to Charles Cowie:  This bus has only the two pumps attached to it, nothing else.  There would be some minor capacitance from the wires themselves, but probably insigificant.

Edit:  The motor is 7,000 HP and has an 8-ton flywheel to extend coastdown time on loss of power, so I imagine connecting it to a grid without regard to phase would be quite dramatic.

Comment: [Why (probably) your question will be shortly closed](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). This isn't a forum and basically asking for opinions on half-baked information is a no no. *You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.* So, your question might be doing someone a disservice.

Comment: If it's an induction motor, then it won't act as a generator when power is removed. You can use induction motors as generators but it takes special arrangements, which amount to running the motor slightly faster, not slower, than the synchronous (supply) frequency.

Comment: As Brian Drummond says, the motor will not be able to act as a generator very well with nothing connected to it. If there are power factor compensation capacitors or anything else that remains connected when the feeder breaker opens, there will be more significant generation. However it is difficult to say what the voltage and frequency decline will look like. I have run tests to see with a 240 or 480 V motor of 5 or 10 Hp, but I don't have any records. I think the voltage decline was a few cycles in duration. The frequency decline would be strictly determined by the load and inertia.

Comment: With nothing connected, you are looking at the decay of the magnetic field in the motor. That will be proportional to motor size. For a small motor like 5 or 10 Hp, the field will be pretty much gone in less than half a second. At a couple of hundred Hp in might be something more than a second. It will be pretty difficult to find any real data, but there are situations where it is important to know, so someone may have done more testing than I did.

Comment: I once designed a system in which the motor was accelerated to 60 Hz with a VFD and then transferred to utility power with contactors. There was an audible torque shock when transferring without regard to phase, exact frequency or voltage. I was told that shafts have been known to break that way. I believe that I put in a couple of seconds delay for a motor of 100 Hp or so. Load was sewage lift station pump.

Comment: @CharlesCowie What is having a delay supposed to do? Let the internal motor currents dissipate so the motor is just coasting before connecting it to the utility?

Comment: The time delay allows the residual magnetic field diminish. With a disconnected induction motor there may be some rotor current also, but restarting with a residual magnetic field is what is problematic.

Comment: Charles Cowie; what you are referring to is called a "synchronous transfer" scheme, it is done quite often now. The trick is to use the VFD to OVER speed the motor by a few RPM before initializing the transfer, so that in the ensuing delay to allow the magnetic field to collapse, you don't have to re-accelerate the load. The larger the motor, the longer it takes for the field to collapse by the way, the more steel you have the longer it holds up. I have never seen it go more than 1 second though.

Comment: @JRaef; what I did was not synchronous. We called it an "open transfer." We were not concerned about the need to accelerate the motor, only about avoiding the remanent field adding to the inrush current. My recollection of the motor size and delay time is very vague. That was about 50 years ago.